# How to assert a file

Tags: ansible

I try to find a way to assert the mode of a file.

I tried to used

```
- name: file status
  stat: path=/opt/et/test.txt

- assert:
    that:
      - "st.stat.mode == 644"
```

But obtain always an error, I don't see why ...
my goal is to check if the file have the right permission

Comment: How and where did you run it? What is the exact error? Can you run Ansible in verbose mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a couple of reasons why your example may not be working:

- You are missing `register` in the `stat` task.
- The comparison in `assert` should for `"0644"`

If you change these two things, then you should have something like below. I have added custom messages to display on "success" or "failure":

```yaml
- stat:
    path: '/opt/et/test.txt'
  register: st

- assert:
    that:
      - "st.stat.mode == '0644'"
    success_msg: 'File has correct permissions.'
    fail_msg: 'File permissions are incorrect.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```yml
 -
  name: Check file
  #hosts: all
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: "Check stat"
      stat:
        path: /home/path/to/file
      register: st

# the following task will execute when the file has the desired permissions 0755 in this case
    - name: "Assert rights"
      debug:
        msg: "File has {{ st.stat.mode }}"
      when: st.stat.mode == "0775"
```

Comment: I don't know why, it skipped the task

Comment: Sorry @JoaaFarro my bad I missed mode key when I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html).

This will work like stat (see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#parameter-state)).

```yaml
- name: file status
  file:
    path: /opt/et/test.txt
```

Or if you want to set the correct mode, in case it is wrong, use this:

```yaml
- name: file status
  file:
    path: /opt/et/test.txt
    mode: '0664'
```

You can also set ownership, group etc.

Comment: my goal is to check if my fix are done correctly.
when I fixed the mode previously I would like to check if the new mode has been changed correctly

Comment: if you use the second example, the mode will be as defined in the `mode` option. No more checks are needed.